# Extract the value of nth column in the last line

Tags: shell, csv, unix, sed

I have a .csv file with the following data:

```
Name,Age,Gender
x,10,F
y,20,M
z,30,F
.
.
.
```

The no.of lines in the file always changes when I run something. How can I extract the `Age` for `Name` in the last line of the file. So far, I tried this:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  #extracting the headings and the last line values from the data.csv 
  file
  (head -1 data.csv && tail -1 data.csv) > dummy.txt 
  #this part doesn't work
  (sed -n "Name" data.csv && sed -n "Age" data.csv)>>dummy.txt
```

The above code errors out this:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F "," 'END{print $2}' file
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed -rn '$s/.*,(.*),.*/\1/p' file
```

Output:

```
30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`tail -1 file | cut -d, -f2`
```

- tail -1 gets the last line,
- cut -d specifies the delimeter,
- -f2 specifies the field